# jquery : Getting an attribute's value after it's loaded with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

i have an element loaded with ajax call and i want to get the value of one of his attributes
For example i have the element `<input id="elm" type="text" value="xxxxxx" />` that was loaded to To the DOM. so when i do like this :

```
alert($("#elm").val())
```

it gives me "undefined".

How can i do that?

I know that `.on()` function in jquery tho that kind of things, but it works only with events like clic, hover etc...

Comment: Lets see how you add the element to the dom and where you try to access it.

Comment: Well let's say that i have a <div id="container"> and the ajax request load an other div called <div ="ajax-loaded-content"> that doesn't exist from the begining and ajax loaded it. So in that "ajax-loaded-content" there is a <span id="wanted-element"> that i want to have its content when loading the "ajax-loaded-content" element.